# How do I impute missing variables in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I would like to impute missing values for a variable given the existing values.
In `var2`, we notice that there are a lot of `NA`s.

1. If any 2 ids are the same, then their values for `var2` are the same.
2. If the id has no values for `var2`, like in the case of id==2, then we just output as `NA`.

It should look from `df_old` to `df_new.`

```
 df_old<- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
 id  var1  var2 
  1  A       12    
  1  B       NA    
  1  E       NA    
  2  G       NA
  2  J       NA
 ")

df_new<- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
id  var1  var2 
 1  A       12    
 1  B       12    
 1  E       12    
 2  G       NA
 2  J       NA
")
```

I tried take:

```
df_new<-df_old %>%
        group_by(id) %>%
        mutate(var2=na.omit(var2))
```

I believe it doesn't work because of the second case. I was also wondering if using ifelse would be okay. Need help thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is only one `var2` value per `id` available you could simply do:

```
df_old %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(var2 = min(var2, na.rm = TRUE))

Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
Groups: id [2]

     id   var1  var2
  <int> <fctr> <int>
1     1      A    12
2     1      B    12
3     1      E    12
4     2      G    NA
5     2      J    NA
```

Another option would be:

```
mutate(var2 = var2[1])
```

Comment: Hey, I need help. I just downloaded the latest R software (version 3.3.1) and I have trouble with computing function for each group. Your code gives me 12 for the whole column. I was wondering if theres some sort of bugs in this new version?

Comment: @HNSKD Perhaps you have loaded the plyr package?  Try `dplyr:: mutate(var2 = min(var2, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: @HNSKD Hm, can't help with that, sorry. I used R version 3.3.0 with dplyr 0.5.0

Comment: @beetroot how do we do imputations if `var2` is a character variable instead? For instance what if 12 is changed to P?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`, but unlike `dplyr`, for groups that have all NA, we have to specify `NA` to return or else it will give `Inf`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_old)[, var2 := if(any(!is.na(var2))) min(var2, na.rm = TRUE) 
            else NA_integer_, by = id]
df_old    
#    id var1 var2
#1:  1    A   12
#2:  1    B   12
#3:  1    E   12
#4:  2    G   NA
#5:  2    J   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

By now there is tidyimpute package available in CRAN which looks like it might do the trick

"Functions and methods for imputing missing values (NA) in tables and list
patterned after the tidyverse approach of 'dplyr' and 'rlang'; works with
data.tables as well."

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyimpute/tidyimpute.pdf

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Here's the link, but I think that package is dead...
https://github.com/decisionpatterns/tidyimpute